# Enable reverse proxy and block access to the original port

Tags: nginx, server

I am hosting an app (Kibana) on port 5601. I want to restrict access to it by whitelisting IPs, so I am trying to host it behind Nginx. Below is my Nginx conf.

```
server {
  listen *:5700;
  server_name _;
  allow 10.20.30.40; # My IP
  deny all;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5601;
  }
}
```

It works as only I can access the app on port `5700` and everyone else gets a `403`. However, others can directly goto `localhost:5601` and bypass the whole security. How do I stop direct access to port `5601`?

Comment: You have to configure a firewall so port 5601 is closed to the outside. You'll always be able to access it from localhost (otherwise not even nginx would be able to perform the proxying).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localhost:5601` is a connection only accessible to users/processes running on the same host that is running Nginx & Kibana. It needs to be there so that Nginx can `proxy_pass` traffic to Kibana.

However, I think you are talking about external users also connecting to port 5601 from remote systems.

Kibana does not need to listen to traffic from external systems on port 5601. Note that by default at least some Kibana installs do not listen to external systems and you may not need to make any changes.

However to be sure:

1. Edit your `kibana.yml` file (possibly /etc/kibana/kibana.yml)
2. Ensure that `server.host: "localhost"` is the only server.host line and is not commented out
3. Restart Kibana

To further manage your system using best practices. I would strongly recommend operating some form of firewall and only opening access to ports and protocols which you expect external users to need.

Comment: Thanks Steve. If anyone is looking for the answer, here's what I did: Update `server.host: "127.0.0.1"` and kept my nginx config file as it is.